# Не получается настроить шлюз

Tags: сеть, debian, шлюз, локальная-сеть

Есть роутер, пк1 (Debian) и пк2 (Windows 10). Подключено все последовательно - от роутера к пк1 и от пк1 к пк2. Хочу, чтоб и на пк1 и на пк2 был интернет и оба они были видны в сети. До этого поднимал мост и был только пк2, сейчас пытался настроить шлюз и ничего не получается. Ip пк1 - 192.168.1.100 (enp0s25), пк2 - 192.168.1.105 (enx00e04c361436). Уже вторые сутки пытаюсь хоть что-то сделать

Comment: У меня 1 роутер.. в него подключен кабель с улицы) к этому роутеру подключено 2 ПК по кабелю и пару устройсв по wifi и все работает) прям магия :) В чем именно у вас проблема, после которой вы не можете двигаться дальше?)

Comment: `и оба они были видны в сети` им дается IP типа **192.168.0.102** в роутере можно пробросить на внеший, тогда айпи будет ваш (провайдера).. а так как провайдер дает только один айпи...